# Binding a grid using a BindingList but creates an exception like im trying to bind to a dbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When i try to do this:

```
 BindingList<PurchaseInvoiceSplit> datasource =
                new BindingList<PurchaseInvoiceSplit>(
                    _db.PurchaseInvoiceSplits.Where(
                        p => p.BookingCharge == _currentCharge.C_ID).ToList());

            gridPurchaseCharges.DataSource = datasource;
```

i get this:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet,
DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, 
for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to
 DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For     
ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of
```

I'm using the .ToList() so i can't understand why i have this error. I know i'm doing something stupid any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a mis-written line on an inititalisation event related to one of the drop downs in the grid. I was sure I checked all those but clearly not..

Still it was strange that the IDE was not catching it and it was a popup run-time error.